# MongoDB continue pull from current document

Tags: mongodb

For example i have this structure:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ce7b49074b355233e6e2fb"),
    "gifts" : [
        {
            "gid" : "lala",
            "reserv" : [
                555,
                666
            ]
        },
        {
            "gid" : "bebe",
            "reserv" : [
                888,
                555
            ]
        }
    ],
    "uid" : 123
}
```

I want to pull "555" from all "reserv" and from all documents by "uid" and content of "reserv":

1) This query find first 555 and pull it, but second 555 in document not pull:

```
db.test.update({uid : 123, 'gifts.reserv': 555}, {'$pull' : {'gifts.$.reserv' : 555}}, {multi : true})
```

2) This query nothing do:

```
db.test.update({uid : 123, 'gifts.reserv': 555}, {'$pull' : {'gifts.reserv' : 555}}, {multi : true})
```

So i can't to do continue update of last updating document.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it isn't possible. Best thing you can do is:

- do a find on your collection to get the document you want.
- on the document, count the amount of gifts that has a `reserv` of `555`
- execute the `update` + `pull` that amount of times.

Comment: So, i think that this is "spike".
Better decision is rebuild collection to unwind gifts array or make separate collection for gifts.reserv.

Comment: what do you mean with "spike"?

Comment: Bad decision of this question.

Answer (score 0):

multi will have no effect here because Setting multi to true will look into multiple documents but here the same value occurs in multiple sub documents. So you need to manipulate through the sub documents.

so you should try something like this.

```
while(db.test.find({uid : 123,'gifts.reserv':555}).count()!=0)
{
    db.test.update(
        {uid : 123,'gifts.reserv':555},
        {$pull:{'gifts.$.reserv':555}}
    )
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you can do it in one command, however, I wonder if this would be efficient if it would happen over a lot of subdocuments, because it executes the `db.test.find({uid : 123,'gifts.reserv':555}).count()` every time.